# Расширение "WHL"

Tags: windows

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как открыть файл с расширением "WHL".

Comment: @Русский Медведь, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Учитывая тематику форума, подозреваю, что это Python-пакет. Тогда установить его можно примерно так:

```
pip install wheel
pip install some-package.whl
```

Comment: Я начинающий, объясните, пожалуйста, более подробно. Мне именно нужно открыть программу cx_Freeze с расширением "WHL" для компиляции моей программы.

Comment: первая строчка нужна только, если нужно создавать свои "колёса". @Русский Медведь `pip install cx_Freeze*.whl` устанавливает cx_Freeze пакет из соответствующего `whl` архива. Чтобы использовать cx_Freeze программу, её нужно сначала установить -- `pip` программа это делает. В общем случае `pip install имя-питон-пакета` устанавливает `имя-питон-пакета` Питон программу/библиотеку c https://pypi.python.org . `pip` программа распространяется с последними версиями Питона и её можно установить отдельно. Если слова: "выполнить команду в консоли" не ясны, то можно задать отдельный вопрос.